# How to calculate linear conflicts on a board?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, programming, recreational-mathematics

Thanks to your help to solve previous problems, I have been able to advance in the learning of mathematica. It seems that this project to make a solver for the 8-puzzle has surpassed my abilities in mathematica, since I have not been able to do a function that calculates the amount of linear conflicts given a board, ***it is very important to keep in mind that it should not be Count the zero*** to make this calculation. Searching on the web to reach this [web page](https://algorithmsinsight.wordpress.com/graph-theory-2/a-star-in-general/implementing-a-star-to-solve-n-puzzle/), where the explanation given by the author helped me understand that it is a linear conflict, here is a screenshot, so that you also know what it is.

[image: part one]

[image: part two]

Here is what I have been able to do, very much to my dismay, if it takes zero into account to say how many conflicts there are on a board.

```
sameRow[i_, j_] := Quotient[i-1, 3] == Quotient[j-1, 3];
 adjacentColumn[i_, j_] := Abs[i-j] == 1;
 sameColumn[i_, j_] := Mod[i-1, 3] == Mod[j-1, 3];
 adjacentRow[i_, j_] := Abs[i-j] == 3;
 directos[board_] := Module[{v = Flatten[board]/.0->9},
    Total[Table[If[v[[v[[i]]]] == i &&
         (sameRow[i, v[[i]]] && adjacentColumn[i, v[[i]]] ||
          sameColumn[i, v[[i]]] && adjacentRow[i, v[[i]]]), 1, 0], {i, 1, 9}]]/2];
```

Testit with the board above, we have

```
directos [{[4,2,5},{1,0,6},{3,8,7}}]
```

But if we try it with the next one, we'll notice that it takes zero into account, which should not be.

```
directos[{{1,2,3},{4,5,0},{7,8,6}}]
```

Do you know any way to achieve this goal? It is important to advance in the construction of the solver I am planning to do. Thanks in advance for your help, without which I can not move forward.

Comment: some typos to fix: `Module[{v = Flatten[board] /. 0 -> 9}, Total[....]]`

Comment: @kglr Thank you for your observation, and modify them according to your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the condition that `i` and `v[[i]]` cannot be 9 (the value of the blank tile after the replacement `0 -> 9`):

```
ClearAll[directos]
directos[board_] := Module[{v = Flatten[board] /. 0 -> 9}, 
   Total[Table[Boole[v[[i]] != 9 &&  i != 9 && 
    (v[[v[[i]]]] == i && (sameRow[i, v[[i]]] && adjacentColumn[i, v[[i]]] || 
    sameColumn[i, v[[i]]] && adjacentRow[i, v[[i]]]))], {i, 1, 9}]] / 2];
```

The examples in OP:

```
directos[{{4, 2, 5}, {1, 0, 6}, {3, 8, 7}}]
```

> 1

```
directos[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 0}, {7, 8, 6}}]
```

> 0

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I expected more answers to know what improvements I could make, I'm going ahead to know more about MMA.

Comment: @bullitohappy, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.